# Issue with Servlet Multipart request

Tags: java, servlets

I follow [this tutorial](http://www.servletworld.com/servlet-tutorials/servlet-file-upload-example.html) to parse multipart request. To this code in first line I add

```
String user = request.getParameter("username");
```

But my code stop working after that. How can I parse the request.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with that specific line of code. Are you sure the username parameter is being passed in with the request?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`request.getParameter("username");` implies that you are trying to read a form field. In that event, you must read the request parameter and it's value using [`FileItem.getFieldName()`](http://commons.apache.org/fileupload/apidocs/org/apache/commons/fileupload/FileItem.html#getFieldName%28%29) and [`FileItem.getString`](http://commons.apache.org/fileupload/apidocs/org/apache/commons/fileupload/FileItem.html#getString%28%29) methods.

`HttpServletRequest.getParameter` will not work in such an event, since it is meant to be used to process URL-encoded data in the query string or in the POST body.