# Passing a URL parameter from JSP to Servlet

Tags: jsp, servlets, request, url-parameters, http-request-parameters

I'm trying to pass a URL parameter from a JSP to a Sevlet.
My URL is

```
/portal/faces/student.jsp?owner_id=1030303i
```

In my JSP i added this

```
<form action="steg" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
     <input type='text' value='<%=request.getParameter("owner_id")%>' id="owner"/>
     <input type="file" name="file" size="50"  />
            <br />             
            <input type="submit" value="Steganograph" />
        </form>
```

However, in the servlet i did this,

```
              String owner = request.getParameter("owner");
              System.out.println("aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"+owner);
              response.sendRedirect("stegsuccess.jsp?owner_id="+owner);
```

the result that is printed out is null.
Is something wrong there? Anyone that knows how to fix this?
Please advice. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 problems in your code:

1. You didn't give the input field a name. You expected that the `id` attribute of the input element is been used as request parameter name. But this is not true. It's the `name` attribute.

   ```
   <input type="text" name="owner" value="${fn:escapeXml(param.owner_id)}" />
   ```

   *(note: I've taken the liberty to seal a [XSS attack hole](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting) in the `value` attribute for you)*
2. You're using `multipart/form-data` encoding and yet expecting that the request parameters are available by `HttpServletRequest#getParameter()`. This is *by default* not supported. This will only work if you're using a servlet with `@MultipartConfig` on a Servlet 3.0 compatible container. Or maybe you're working on an existing project and someone else has already invented a servlet filter which transparently parses `multipart/form-data` requests and fills the request parameter map before passing the request to the servlet. In any case, make sure that you understand how to parse `multipart/form-data` requests: [How to upload files to server using JSP/Servlet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2422468/how-to-upload-files-to-server-using-jsp-servlet/2424824#2424824)

Answer (score 0):

What version of servlets are you using?

> `multipart/form-data` encoded requests are indeed not by default supported by the Servlet API prior to version 3.0. The Servlet API parses the parameters by default using `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` encoding. When using a different encoding, the `request.getParameter()` calls will all return `null`. When you're already on Servlet 3.0 ([Glassfish 3](http://glassfish.dev.java.net), [Tomcat 7](http://tomcat.apache.org), etc), then you can use [`HttpServletRequest#getParts()`](http://java.sun.com/javaee/6/docs/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getParts()) instead.

From https://stackoverflow.com/a/3337115/139010. See also [Issue with Servlet Multipart request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6994517/problem-with-servlet-multipart-request).

Comment: I'm not really too sure what's the version I'm using. I tried using the links you've given me. But it seems that its not working with getValues and returning me to a wrong page. Any idea if there is other method for this?

Comment: Look in web.xml. The top-level element is `<web-app/>` and its `version` and `xsi:schemaLocation` attributes are a hint as to what servlet version you're using.

Answer (score 0):

`sendRedirect()` method wont carry the request object forward. Instead use `RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("yourpage.jsp");rd.forward(req, res)` method which forwards the request object and so the request parameters.

Comment: This is correct from Servlet code of user. If you look at JSP code,the request is `enctype="multipart/form-data"`.So, `request.getParameter("paramName");` will return NULL.